# Filter Results in One Worksheet Based on the Selection in Another Work Sheet in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and I am trying to filter the results in one sheet based on a selection made in another worksheet.  Below, I provide a basic outline of the problem in general terms.

Suppose I have a Sheet A and I filter on dimensions C1 and C2.  Based on this I get 10 rows of my data (the original data is 100 rows, suppose).  Now, I want to display only the values corresponding to these 10 rows in another worksheet B but filtered on a column C3 (not the original columns C1 and C2), i.e., I want to select the 10 different values in Column C3 and show results in sheet B corresponding to these values.

I tried Filter Action but it seems I can create filters based on the filters I have chosen on Sheet A, i.e., C1 and C2.  How can I create a filter corresponding to column C3?

Thanks for your help.  Please let me know if the question is too general or not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't totally understand your question but will try to help with whatever I understood.

You can create a filter for Column 3 in the second sheet and when you use action filter in Sheet 1 in dashboard it shows the data based on the action filter and also the filter for Column 3 set for sheet 2.

You can also use parameter.Firstly create a parameter for column3. Create a calculated field using that parameter and use the calculated field as input for the graph or table you create in sheet 2.

Refer these links for calculated fields and parameter:
https://www.interworks.com/blog/rcurtis/2016/05/26/tableau-deep-dive-parameters-calculated-fields
https://www.interworks.com/blog/anonymous/2012/03/26/how-create-and-use-parameters-tableau